# How to correctly structure frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a simple chat app and I'm having a problem with packing Frames into the main window.
Here is the part of my code:

```py
class MainApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.server_frame = ServerFrame(self)
        self.server_frame.pack(side="left")
    
        self.client_frame = ClientFrame(self)
        self.client_frame.pack(side="left")

        self.chat_frame = ChatFrame(self)
        self.chat_frame.pack(side="right")

        self.additional_frame = AdditionalFrame(self)
        self.additional_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

How can I get it to GUI looks like this:

[image: wanted GUI structure]

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use pack()? From your (very nice) graphic it looks like a grid() layout would be much better.

Comment: @Novel No actually it's not necessary to use pack (), I just thought it would be easier to do this with pack() because I've tried to use grid() but I failed. (im new to tkinter :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack()` is best when all of the widgets need to be in a single row or column. For this I'd recommend `grid()`:

```
class MainApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.server_frame = ServerFrame(self)
        self.server_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
        self.client_frame = ClientFrame(self)
        self.client_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.chat_frame = ChatFrame(self)
        self.chat_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2)

        self.additional_frame = AdditionalFrame(self)
        self.additional_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
```